# Rotating a bone in pose mode also scales it

Tags: animation, rigging

When I rotate the bone, it wasn't supposed to scale it. Here as you can see it scales it:
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRjG1.png)

[[image]
[[image]

Comment: maybe its parent bone has some scale

Comment: @lemon I already applied transforms of the **armature**

Comment: I meant scaled in pose mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the N panel, the bone doesn't scale at all.

What happens is that vertices that move by rotating the Arm.L bone have some weight relatively to some others bones/Vertex Groups which stay still, so the mesh is stretched between theese opposite "forces".

To solve, just remove weights from vertex groups that are not supposed to influence the left arm.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Apparently I was having these intersecting vertices assigned to different groups. That was causing all the mess.